# Unix, Separate-table

Tags: shell, unix

How to put space between these two words without affecting other words.

As you can see, I have two columns here adjusted in decreasing order of age. I want to separate the word NameAge so that each of them be in a cell and its corresponding column. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The command below insert space between lowercase letter and uppercase letter.

```
 sed '1s/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g' orig.txt > split.txt
```

orig.txt:

```
NameAge
Bob      90
Sarah    76
Russel   49
Kate     21
```

split.txt

```
Name Age
Bob      90
Sarah    76
Russel   49
Kate     21
```

**EDIT:**
1 in the sed expression to affect only header, per suggested by @jm666

**EDIT2:**

```
sed '1s/-/ /g' orig.txt > split.txt
```

Turned out that orig.txt looks like this:

```
Name-PersonNumber-Age
Bob      1 90
Sarah    2 76
Russel   3 49
Kate     4 21
```

split.txt

```
Name PersonNumber Age
Bob      1 90
Sarah    2 76
Russel   3 49
Kate     4 21
```

Comment: what did you get?

Comment: it creates a new file.  Say your original file is orig.txt .  With the commnd you should see split.txt in the same directory(folder).   Use your file names instead of orig.txt

Comment: Is "NameAge" has captal N and captal A, and lower case for the rest?  that's what I assumed.

Comment: It was an example: the real one was Name_PersonNumber_Age and I wanted to put space between Name_Person   and    Number_Age

Comment: So you want to replace '_' by ' '?  If that's that case `tr '_' ' ' orig.txt > split.txt`

Comment: @reader The answer works. It puts space between every lowercase and Upercase letters. So from the `Name_PersonNumber_Age` it creates `Name_Person Number_Age`. If it doesn't works for you, the problem is in the question and/or in your data.

Comment: You want 'Name-PersonNumber-Age' to be chaged to 'Name PersonNumber Age' , i.e. replace '-' by ' '? Or you don't know if it is '-' or '_' and every file are different?  I think you have to narrow down what the requirement is...  if it is always delimited by '-', then `tr '-' ' ' orig.txt > split.txt`

Comment: @yosukesabai ... one thing: do the edits only in the 1st line - the OP doesn't want changes on the other lines. Otherwise - nice.

Comment: @jm666 , right, it's going to screw up the rest, if there is some name like YosukeSabai down the road...  I say `head -n 1`  and so on, but it won't be one liner... I may also need awk to align columns if that's @reader want.  Write everything in awk may make more sense.  I just did bare-minimum that should work with the example.

Comment: @yosukesabai just add `1` before the `s`. :) e.g. `sed '1s/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1 \2/g'` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138424/discussion-between-yosukesabai-and-jm666).

Comment: tr seems to have problem with hyphen, sorry.  Try this instead, `sed '1s/-/ /g' orig.txt > split.txt`.   This will replace any hyphen in first line into space.